# How do I select column values by selective pattern matching from a subquery

Tags: sql, string, pattern-matching, sql-like, string-matching

##Using SQL server

How do I select column values by selective pattern matching from a subquery?

For Example, I have data in the format **column1  = '123/2b3/abcdefghw1/stuvwxyz28'** I would like to get output from below query with matching values in subquery as **column1 like '%abcdefgh%stuvwxyz%'**

my sql query is something like this:

**select * from table1
where column1 in (select coulmn1 from table2
where column2 is not null)**

so, the above subquery would be returning multiple values of column1 in the format '123/2b3/abcdefghw1/stuvwxyz28', then outer query should be returning values from table1 where column1 matches pattern '%abcdefgh%stuvwxyz%'

Now I can do this for single value but I would like to generalize this pattern.
I am using below to extract subparts of columns values as :

1. left(split(column1,'/')[2],8)  which gives output as 'abcdefgh' for above example
2. left(split(column1,'/')[3],8)  which gives output as 'stuvwxyz' for above example

I am sure I should be using concat with above logics to generate the pattern but I am not quite sure how to do that.

*****************************************************************z

Please refer below example to better understand my goal:

There are three tables:

**TableA**

**row_numA,Column1,column2,column3**

1,101/212B/EDSVVJABHG1/WDNHNJCNHG3,4,a1

2,101/4VC3/PHLAPACBHG1/PHLAPA40HG2,null,a3

3,701/11G5/LSAJCAWZPQ2/LSANCARCPL1,6,b1

4,102/2NJGF/AMSTNLLRHG2/AMSTNLPXHG1,2,b4

5,101/VKYR/JRCYNJ67WDD/NYCMNYZRWDN,null,c5

**TableB**

**row_numB,name,column1,id**

1,b4,101/212B/EDSVVJABHG1/WDNHNJCNHG3,null

2,c5,101/4VC3/PHLAPACBHG1/PHLAPA40HG2,id2

3,a1,701/11G5/LSAJCAWZPQ2/LSANCARCPL1,null

4,a3,102/2NJGF/AMSTNLLRHG2/AMSTNLPXHG1,null

5,b1,101/VKYR/JRCYNJ67WDD/NYCMNYZRWDN,id5

6,b2,101/212B/EDSVVJABHJ1/WDNHNJCNHB3,id6

7,a4,701/11G5/LSAJCAWZPR4/LSANCARCPF2,id7

8,c2,701/11G5/LSAJCAWZPU3/LSANCARCPS5,null

9,d1,102/2NJGF/AMSTNLLRHK4/AMSTNLPXHH7,id9

**TableC**

**row_numC,c_id,c_len**

1,id3,null

2,id4,11

3,null,23

4,id5,null

5,id6,7

6,null,null

7,null,5

8,id7,10

9,id8,null

---

**Goal_1**: select coulmn1 from tableA where column2 is not null

**Expected output**:

Column1

101/212B/EDSVVJABHG1/WDNHNJCNHG3

701/11G5/LSAJCAWZPQ2/LSANCARCPL1

102/2NJGF/AMSTNLLRHG2/AMSTNLPXHG1

---

**Goal_2**: Using above output match with column1 in tableB using string matching like: %EDSVVJAB%WDNHNJCN%  ("%"<"first 8 values after second /">%<"first 8 values after third /">%)

**Expected output from tableB:**

**row_numB,name,column1,id**

1,b4,101/212B/**EDSVVJAB**HG1/**WDNHNJCN**HG3,null

6,b2,761/325L/**EDSVVJAB**HJ1/**WDNHNJCN**HB3,id6

4,a3,158/277GF/**AMSTNLLR**HG2/**AMSTNLPX**HG1,null

9,d1,102/2NJGF/**AMSTNLLR**HK4/**AMSTNLPX**HH7,id9

3,a1,901/11G5/**LSAJCAWZ**PQ2/**LSANCARC**PL1,null

7,a4,725/12K5/**LSAJCAWZ**PR4/**LSANCARC**PF2,id7

8,c2,881/12LP/**LSAJCAWZ**PU3/**LSANCARC**PS5,null

---

**Goal_3**: select data Where id field is populated for common highlighted values of column1

**Expected output:**

**row_numB,name,column1,id**

6,b2,101/212B/EDSVVJABHJ1/WDNHNJCNHB3,id6

9,d1,102/2NJGF/AMSTNLLRHK4/AMSTNLPXHH7,id9

7,a4,701/11G5/LSAJCAWZPR4/LSANCARCPF2,id7

---

**Goal_4**:
Join above output with TableC to get c_len not null values

**Expected output from tableC:**

**row_numC,c_id,c_len**

5,id6,7

8,id7,10

This is the final result set required.
I am seeking help in achieving goal_2 and goal_3 (preferably in single query)

Comment: Can you clarify your question on what your data and tables look like, and what you would like the final results and query to look like? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Added example and goal I would like to achieve in detail.